# How to convert to text the Chrome cache gzipped data?

Tags: google-chrome, caching, gzip, converters

I was overwrite my CSS file, but the original is in my mobile's Chrome cache. I found the file in cache, but if I opened the link in the cache list I see something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 25 Jul 2015 16:58:50 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: Host,Accept-Encoding
Last-Modified: Fri, 17 Jul 2015 10:51:25 GMT
ETag: "14ff-51b0ff82ba5ad-gzip"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 1483
Content-Type: text/css
00000000: 48 01 00 00 03 08 04 00 87 ec 5a 51 4c 7a 2e 00  H.........ZQLz..
00000010: 18 97 5c 51 4c 7a 2e 00 04 01 00 00 48 54 54 50  ..\QLz......HTTP
00000020: 2f 31 2e 31 20 32 30 30 20 4f 4b 00 44 61 74 65  /1.1 200 OK.Date
00000030: 3a 20 53 61 74 2c 20 32 35 20 4a 75 6c 20 32 30  : Sat, 25 Jul 20
00000040: 31 35 20 31 36 3a 35 38 3a 35 30 20 47 4d 54 00  15 16:58:50 GMT.
```

How can I convert this back to a CSS text file?

Comment: I hope this helps http://www.alexkorn.com/blog/2010/05/how-to-recover-deleted-javascript-files-using-the-cache-in-chrome-or-firefo/

Comment: It doesn't look gzipped (= compressed). How do you know it is?

Comment: The header said this:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 25 Jul 2015 16:58:50 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: Host,Accept-Encoding
Last-Modified: Fri, 17 Jul 2015 10:51:25 GMT
ETag: "14ff-51b0ff82ba5ad-gzip"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 1483
Content-Type: text/css

Comment: @Kiloreux: unfortunately not helps.